# Images in collectionview

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Have collection view and trying to display images from group folder in collection view cells. Index wise it should start from 0 but it is displaying images from index 1 and collection view cell at index 0 is showing empty.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
return 6;
 }

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
 {


 Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

// make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value
cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section];

// load the image for this cell
NSString *imageToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row];
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad];

return cell;
}

  // the user tapped a collection item, load and set the image on the detail view controller

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

    // load the image, to prevent it from being cached we use 'initWithContentsOfFile'
    NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_full", selectedIndexPath.row];
    NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    detailViewController.image = image;
}
 }
```

why cell at index 0 is showing no image. Collection view is showing images from cell at index 1 except from 0. Am i doing something wrong in my code.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: I bet you don't have a "`0.jpg`" file, do you?

Comment: thanks 0.jpg was missing